# How to add string to window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, href

Any ideas how can I write this:

```js
var hashValue = "#" + window.location.hash.substr(1);
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(hashValue).offset().top
        
}, 500);
```

Without getting this error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

It is working like that, but I don't want to see this error in the console.

Comment: Why do you take `# + substr(1)` of the hash? Why not simply `window.location.hash` and check if it is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var hashValue = "#" + window.location.hash.substring(1);

$([ document.documentElement, document.body ]).animate({
  scrollTop: hashValue === '#' ? 0 : $(hashValue).offset().top
}, 500);
```

Let’s just assume `window.location.hash` is the empty string. In this case `hashValue` is `"#"`.

So the jQuery call `$(hashValue)` doesn’t recognize it as an element ID, so it throws a syntax error.